Amova using haplotype freq data
I want to perform an Amova based on haplotypes which I extracted from mitochondrial DNA. Based on these sequences I want to see if there is any significant population structuring going on.
At first I tried to convert my fasta files into a genind class, so I could do the analysis using the amova function from poppr. However, it did not work, I think because this method is mostly used for diploid DNA. So, instead I tried to calculate a distance matrix based on my frequency data, using the amova function from pegas.
haplo_freq <- data.frame(
Population = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
Hap_1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
Hap2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 11, 5),
Hap3 = c(0, 5, 2, 0, 5, 12),
Hap4 = c(5, 0, 0, 3, 19, 14),
Hap5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0),
Hap6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0),
Hap7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 1),
Hap8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
)
rownames(haplo_freq) <- haplo_freq$Population
haplo_freq <- haplo_freq[, -1]
dist_matrix <- dist(haplo_freq, method = "euclidean")
populations <- factor(rownames(haplo_freq))  # or create a factor variable for grouping if you have additional levels
amova_result <- amova(dist_matrix ~ populations, nperm=1000)
print(amova_result)

However, I get the following error: Error in amova(dist_matrix ~ populations, nperm = 1000) : unused argument (nperm = 1000). Weirdly, enough, I am still able to print the results from the amova, but I am not sure if I can trust the output. Could anyone help me?

The nperm argument is for pegas implementation of AMOVA. If you want to use it, add argument method = "pegas". Otherwise, it uses ade4 implementation by default, and the nperm argument is ignored. It shouldn't affect your results, but to be sure try to rerun either without the argument or with the proper method.
